# Is there any sarcasm in "gun lobby protecting its own"?

Tags: sarcasm

In [Runaway Jury (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_Jury), a plaintiff attorney, Rohr meets Ranking Fitch, a jury consultant of the defendants,
the gun manufacturers:

> Fitch: Nice suit. very "of the people."
>
> Rohr: Yours is nicer. What would you call it, "**gun lobby protecting
> its own**"? Swank shoes.

Is there any sarcasm in "gun lobby protecting its own"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly a come-back to the slight insult of "of the people". Fitch seems to complement Rohr's suit, but the "of the people" suggests it is rather cheap.

Rohr comments that Fitch's suit is clearly very expensive, but has been paid for by money from "bad" people, the gun lobby.

Rohr is saying that Fitch may have money, but only by associating with evil people.